# Regular expression to check characters in a string

Tags: php, regex

I have a text to validate using regex,

Text field is allowed to have all the characters a-z and 0-9 except for alphabets (i,o,q).

I tried something like this but cannot get it to work `'/[^(oOiIqQ)]/'`

Comment: So you've got a problem that you're going to solve with regex? Now you have two problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way for exclusions like this is to use negative lookahead. State what you want:

```
/^(?:[a-z0-9])+\z/i
```

Then exclude the items you don't want:

```
/^(?:(?![ioq])[a-z0-9])+\z/i
```

Comment: @Qtax: In this case I think it just complicates matters, but I'll change it anyway to make it "correcter" :)

Comment: It's not needed at all in the first expression, eg `/^[a-z0-9]+\z/i`, but I guess you could be using it to emphasize the similarity between them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use parenthesis in [ ... ].

You have to use something like '/[0-9a-hj-npr-zA-HJ-NPR-Z]/'

If you want to be sure your text only has those characters, use:

```
'/^[0-9a-hj-npr-zA-HJ-NPR-Z]+$/'
```

So you can match a string containing any number of those characters, and only those.

Answer (score 0):

This might works: `[a-hj-npr-z]` Maybe you can add the flag `i` at the end of your regexp for case insensibility.

(yours will allow EVERY characters except those you specified)

```
if (preg_match('#^[0-9a-hj-npr-z]+$#i', $string)) {
   //string OK
}
```

Comment: You'll also need to anchor the start & end of the string, or it will match if at least one character matches.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someting like this `/^[0-9a-hj-npr-z A-HJ-NPR-X]+$/`

Answer (score 0):

I would assume a little change to your's and would try:

```
^[^oOiIqQ]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple solution for this which takes in consideration negative regexing (which makes the regex shorter and much readable)

```
[^ioqIOQ]+
```